# jquery selector: select an element whose child has an attribute

Tags: jquery

Hello: here is the menu I have:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-header">Menu</li>
  <li><a href="loggedon.php">Menu pricipal</a></li>
  <li><a href="maFiche.php">Ma fiche</a></li>
  <li><a href="messages.php">Messages reçus</a></li>
  <li><a href="favorits.php">Mes favoris</a>
  <li><a href="#">Mes coeurs</a> 
  <li><a href="#">Mes photo</a>   
  </li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
</ul>
<script>
$("li").addClass("active");
</script>
```

This script adds active to ALL li.

My goal is to add the class to an li whose child a href has "maFiche.php" for instance.

ANy clue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [the :has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) :

```
$('li:has([href="maFiche.php"])')
```